# VS Code -- Are there user/support forums or an IRC channel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There seem to be multiple places to ask questions, report bugs, feature requests, etc.  Here, Github, MSDN.  It's kind of all over the place.  Are there any **README** documents that I'm missing that discuss support options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a rough guide of which communications channel to use:

- For issues / feature requests, please file a GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new
- For general "how to" questions, StackOverflow is probably your best bet
- For other discussions, try https://gitter.im/Microsoft/vscode or [Twitter](https://twitter.com/code)

Comment: gitter.im, IRC, Slack, Skype, or something. Chat is useful @Microsoft
It enables the community to answer/communicate instantly.

Answer (score 5):

The IRC channel on Freenode is ##vs-code.

Comment: for some reason there's also #VSCode (the most popular one by population count) and ##VSCode (the least popular one)

Answer (score 3):

there appear to be 3 separate VSCode support channels on freenode, i ordered them by apparent population:

irc://irc.freenode.net/#VSCode (24 people connected as of writing)

irc://irc.freenode.net/##vs-code (22 people connected as of writing)

irc://irc.freenode.net/##VSCode (10 people connected as of writing)

as of writing means: 2019-05-26T12:40:21+00:00 (ISO 8601)

Answer (score 2):

Today the answer to this question is #vscode on the liberachat network (because freenode.net is dead).