# Python takes a long time highlighting on VS Code WSL Connection after I duplicated workspace in new window

Tags: visual-studio-code

Previously Python highlighting in my Visual Studio Code works just fine. Then I opened the same folder in new window by `Workspace : Duplicate As Workspace In New Window`, I didn't do anything else aside from this but suddenly VS Code takes MINUTES just for highlighting python function and modules. This NEVER happens before and I'm opening the exact same unmodified file.

EDIT : At first highlighting doesn't work at all but then I saw it highlights everything after MINUTES. I tried to reboot my laptop and VSCode but still doesn't fix. This only occurs on my WSL connection, the local Windows is fine

Comment: Have you tried asking people on the [vscode IRC chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56313564/696836)? You can also search their issue tracker. If you have a debugger, you can try attaching it to the process and see where it's blocking, and then file an issue/bug.

Comment: Make sure that you have installed Python extension (if you are using Python extension from Microsoft) in the WSL too. Also [make sure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands) that your Linux distro runs on WSL2 since WSL1 has relatively poor file system performance.

Comment: @YashojaLakmith I do, pylance and python in my local and in WSL. I also use WSL2..